# P type degenerate semiconductors band tail

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

How is the band tail formed in P type degenerate semiconductors? Shouldn't the lower energy state of the impurity  band be equal to the acceptor level before the degenerate doping?

For normal doping there is just one energy level inside the band gap filled with electrons(N type) or completely empty(P type) called donor and acceptor levels.

[image]

In the case of a degenerate semiconductor an impurity band is formed.But how is the tail band (which connects the impurity band with the conduction band(N type degenerate semiconductor) or the valence band(P type degenerate semiconductor))formed?.

For N type degenerate semiconductors we create new energy levels from bottom to top starting from the lowest energy level(donor level of normal doping)  until the impurity band 'touches' with the conduction band.

But for P type degenerate semiconductors if we create new energy levels from bottom to top starting from the lowest energy level(acceptor level of normal doping)it doesn't touch the valence band, there is the  gap between the impurity band and the valence band.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think this question needs more clarity, perhaps even a diagram: it is not lcear what you refer to by *heavy doping* and what is the situation before thsi doping (apparently there area lready impurities. Also, n-case and p-case are really similar, if one thinks respectively in  terms of electrons and holes.

Comment: @Vadim if someone has study band diagrams of semiconductors it is pretty clear.Ok fine i will edit my answer.

Comment: Then the answer to your question should be pretty clear as well ;) However, the terminology and diagrams vary from one book to another - so we may simply not speaking the same language.

Comment: You are missing that the acceptor levels grow ‘down’. Flip your perspective to that of a hole. Kind of like a world map with south up.

Comment: Jon okay I got it!